# App crashes when I push segue from one view controller to another, and then try to go back to the first view controller

Tags: ios, segue

The app starts with viewController1. I have a standard push segue to viewController2, and then another push segue from viewController2 to viewController3. In viewController3 I have a custom back button that I would like to send the user back to viewController2 (or going back to viewController1 would be fine as well).

The custom back button code is this:

```
- (IBAction)customBackButton:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This works as a back button for viewController2 (as in, if I go from viewController1 to viewController2, and use this code in viewController2, it successfully brings me back to viewController1). However, when I use it in viewController3, I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** - [__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:}: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Is there a better way to do a custom back button? I don't want to just have it be another push segue back to viewController2, because this seems to retain the viewController3 object and when I then go *back* to viewController 3(after hitting the custom back button) the functionally is messed up.

Comment: What you're doing looks correct. You should add an exception breakpoint to see which line is causing that error. It's not even clear from your question which controller has the error.

Comment: I would say you have an issue in viewcontroller2, not in the navigation. The controller will be presented but not instanciated, could that spoil some arrays of yours?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is because viewcontroller2 is a subclass of viewController1, and methods in viewController1 automatically start running when you open viewController2.

Comment: Why should anything in vc1 start? being a subclass should have no impact on the instances (unless you have static stuff or class methods in there)

Comment: I think you need to show us what you're doing in vc1 and vc2 to see if vc2 being a subclass of vc1 is the problem. What array is causing the problem? Is it created in vc1 or vc2?